# pass in DOM element to setClassToggle

Tags: jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm trying to pass in a DOM element that I get with jquery into the `setClassToggle(element, class)`, but I keep getting this error. What am I missing here?

> (ScrollMagic.Scene) -> ERROR calling method 'setClassToggle()':
>   Invalid element supplied.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cf53b6ac/)

```
      <div class="grid-item" data-parallax="bouble">
        <div class="container quote start" id="first">
          <h2>"</h2>
          <p>Vestibulum vitae congue nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin pretium mauris a quam molestie porttitor. Nulla vel molestie enim. Aenean suscipit cursus volutpat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



  var parallaxClass = $(this).data('parallax');
  var element = $(this).find('.container');

  if (parallaxClass === 'bouble') {
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: this,
        triggerHook: 0.7
      })
      .addIndicators()
      .setClassToggle(element, parallaxClass)
      .addTo(controller);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the ScrollMagic docs](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#setClassToggle). The `element` attribute that `setClassToggle` receives should be a *selector*, not the actual element itself.

> `element`: A Selector targeting one or more elements or a DOM object that is supposed to be modified.`
>
> ```
> // add multiple classes to multiple elements defined by the selector
> '.classChange' scene.setClassToggle(".classChange", "class1 class2 class3");
> ```